# Ошибка 500...SpringBoot ... В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

К сожалению получаю ошибку 500...Подскажите в чем может быть проблема...делаю по учебнику Spring в действии 2022 года

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xml:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmls="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Order From</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/orders}" th:object="${tacoOrder}">
    <h1>Order your taco creations!</h1>
    <img th:src="@{/images/taco.jpg}"/>
    <h3>Your tacos in this order:</h3>
    <a th:href="@{/design}">Design another taco</a>
    <br>
    <ul>
        <li th:each="taco : ${tacos}">
            <span th:text="${taco.name}">Taco name</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Deliver my taco masterpieces to...</h3>
    <label for="deliveryName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryName}"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
2022-10-17 22:23:32.401 ERROR 18316 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/orderForm.html]")] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'tacoOrder' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скопируйте ваш код и сообщение об ошибке вместо скриншотов в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение - погуглить github spring in action 6 и посмотреть как правильно .Чтоб не париться просто папку с нужной главой скачать и открыть ее как проект в IDE и все должно работать.  А дальше уже смотреть , что делал не так.

У тебя неправильно написана th:each. Ты либо писать должен *{tacos} либо ${tacoOrder.tacos}  плюс надо было еще скинуть клас контроллера, может ты в модель не добавляешь объект  . Возможно в этом проблема. А так чтоб не мучаться,  сделай как я выше написал просто скачай с гит хаб папку и запусти